# how can I turn off the scene light for a render in blender eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

I am working on a little project for 14th february, but when I turn off scene lights, they aren't turned off in the render.I am using Blender 2.93

[image]

with scene lights[image]

without scene lights
[image]

Comment: if you mean it doesn't count when you make a final render (Render > Render Image), it's the way it is supposed to work, these options are only working for Rendered preview

Answer (score 4):

Select all the lights in your scene.

[image]

Press '**M**' and create a new collection with your lights

[image]

Uncheck this box before rendering

[image]

Recheck it if you want lights back.